# How to add google Closure namespace to Javascript class

Tags: javascript, google-closure

I have a question how to add google Closure namespace to javascript class. This works:

```
goog.provide('mynamespace1.mynamespace2.Myclass');
goog.require('goog.dom');

mynamespace1.mynamespace2.Myclass = function(param1) {
  this._param1 = param1;
  this.public_method();
  var private_method = function() {
  };
  private_method();  // Not really sure how to access it by public_method();
};

mynamespace1.mynamespace2.Myclass.prototype.public_method = function() {

};

// Test1
var test1 = new mynamespace1.mynamespace2.Myclass(1);
test1.public_method();
```

But, if javascript class definition is:

```
goog.provide('mynamespace1.mynamespace2.MyAnotherclass');
goog.require('goog.dom');

function MyAnotherclass(param1) {
  var that = this;
  this._param1 = param1;

  this.private_method = function() {
  };

  this.private_method();

  that.public_method = function() {
  };
};

// Test 2
var test2 = new MyAnotherclass(1);
test2.public_method();
```

How to add namespace? Thank you very much for help.

Comment: I found the answer. change function MyAnotherclass(param1) {} to mynamespace1.mynamespace2.MyAnotherclass = function(param1) {}

Comment: OP, you can provide an answer to your own question so that others can find it.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, change it to

```
mynamespace1.mynamespace2.MyAnotherclass = function(param1) {
    ...
};
```

Comment: That's a pretty shameful attempt at rep scavenging :-/

Comment: You might want to check out [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) for what is considered the appropriate way to move another person's comment to an answer.

Comment: @Mathletics, what? This is a Q&A site. There's an on-topic question. There should be an on-topic answer. I don't care if it's mine or someone else's, or whatever. Comments are intented to be somewhat transitory, not permanent. If I could make user3792705 post an answer I would. But I can't. All I can do is improve this situation the best I can. Google Closure is unpopular enough I doubt there will be single upvote. But I like Closure, and I try to help wherever I can. I'm not here for the rep. Hardly shameful.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara, done. That is very unobvious. Thanks for the tip.